# Fetching data from array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I've finally figured out how to fetch data from Google Analytics to website, unfortunately output (`print_r`) is PHP array inside an array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 196 ) )
```

I need to get the `number 196` & "save" it as variable in order to use it in calculations or output it, any ideas how to achieve this?

**Im looking for overall solution/principle/rule because some data is even array inside array inside array etc.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to grab the first array element -*position 0* - and from this inner array you pick the first element - *also position 0* - which is `196`, Check this: [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/k3d6-h80s) - *hit run to execute*

```
// getting 196
echo $myArr[0][0];
```

Comment: Thanks! Too long pause from programming.

Comment: Yo welcome, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$newVariable = $yourArray[0][0];

echo $newVariable; //This will echo the answer.

//This answer is self explanatory.
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems I've had a too long pause from programming.